# How to change UDF label on the screen

Tags: acumatica

A UDF was added via a Customization Project.  Now the user wants to change the label showing on the screen.  I have changed the [PXUIField(displayName="OldLabel")] attribute to "NewLabel".  Published the project, but no change on the screen.  I tried changing the UDF's Label Text property to "NewLabel", but again, no change after publication.  I would delete the customization and start over, but the customization does a lot more than just add this UDF and was written by someone else.  I don't want to miss something.  Is there a way to delete the UDF from this customization project and add it in a new one with the correct label?  I can't find a way to remove a UDF.

Comment: I usually edit the project xml. You can do this if you export (then edit) and import or even better click on the customization project and then in the customization project window under edit click edit xml. Then take out the field information. Something still tells me that its not going to make a difference. Did you try to unpublish all. then publish again your changes?

Comment: That worked Bendan.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Perfect. I suggest posting your own answer with the option that solved your question to help others.